# Get elements from a JSONArray when the elements have no name

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have google it all day and it looks like I'm the only one who has this problem (strangely?)

Well I have this:

```
"genres": [
"Animation",
"Kids & Family",
"Science Fiction & Fantasy",
"Comedy"
],
```

No problem geting out the array with:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = res.getJSONArray("genres");
```

But now? I don't know the names in the jsonArray. I can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

But how do I get out the values of the elements in the array?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Douglas Crockford's JSON library? If so you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    String value = jsonArray.getString(i);
    // do something with value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONArray` and `JsonArray` are from different library so you can not cast them to gather 
you should put output in a file and create a `JsonArray` again from it